# How to get Solr Core Admins API response in JSON

Tags: solr

Solr core admin API returns response in XML like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">2155</int></lst><str name="core">test</str>
</response>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get this back in JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to append the link with `&wt=json`.

This will give you the output in JSON format.